# Why we should specify column name in where clause at inner join when have same column name?

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

I have the query

```
 select gltree.*,tsacc.confirm,tsacc.acc_no,commacc.* from tsacc  
  inner join commacc on tsacc.acc_no = commacc.acc_no and tsacc.glcode = commacc.glcode
  inner join gltree on tsacc.glcode = gltree.glcode
  where gltree.glcode = 12738
```

in this query two specified tables have **'glcode'** column name , *so 
why I should specify table name in where clause eg. gltree.glcode* and can't use only glcode without table name ? As we have just one glcode in executed query ?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have **threes** columns with that name (`tsacc.glcode`, `commacc.glcode` and `gltree.glcode`), so you need to tell the database which one you mean.

The list of columns in the select list is evaluated as the last step when processing the statement. So when the DB processes the where clause it does not "know" which of them you are actually using (you could use all of them).

Plus: with an inner join it does indeed not matter, but if you were using an outer join it would make a big difference which of those three columns is used in the where clause.